# MySQL SELECT from multiple columns from tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

I am trying to retrieve information from a mysql database.
I have the following tables:

> Qualifications(qualificationid, qualificationname, personid,status)
>
> Address(addressid, addressline1,city,province,areacode,personid)
>
> score(scoreid, score.choices,personid,jobid)

I use typed the following mysql statement to retrieve the data

```
SELECT score.personid, qualifications.qualificationname, score.score
FROM
Qualifications, Score, Address
WHERE
score.jobid=58
AND
qualifications.qualificationName ='Human Resource Management'
AND
aadress.province ='Western Cape'
ORDER BY score.score
LIMIT 0,20;
```

this seems to work for everything else but doesn't restrict the province to western cape.

Comment: province is "western cape" just like that? any chance to have space or other chars? you can try: UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(aadress.province))) =UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM('Western Cape'))) ; OR aadress.province LIKE '%Western Cape%'. Hope this helps

Comment: Looks like a typo: address.province instead of aadress.province

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use joins? Like so:

```
SELECT s.personid, q.qualificationname, s.score
  FROM Score s
  INNER JOIN Qualifications q ON q.personid = s.personid AND q.qualificationName ='Human Resource Management'
  INNER JOIN Address a ON a.personid = s.personid AND a.province ='Western Cape'
  WHERE s.jobid = 58
  ORDER BY s.score DESC
  LIMIT 0,20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define relations. The system now has no clue how Addresses relate to Scores or Qualifications in your example. By adding a `GROUP BY score.personid` and `AND score.personid = address.personid` and `score.personid = qualifications.personid` you might fix your problems.

Also, using `JOINS` is probably more efficient as it does basically the same.